# Python: Binning data with a weight

Tags: python, binning, weighting

I have got a dataset with strong noise, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0,10,N)
y = x + 20 * np.random.rand(N)
```

I want to bin the data for a given `binsize` (or `binnumber`). By that I basically just mean a `Δx`. The binned data should be weighted by a gaussian function that you can think of as a gaussian that is extended over the y-axis weighting the data depending on the distance of the expectation value `µ`. Also, I want the data to give me the `1σ-error`.

I know about `numpy.digitize` and `scipy.stats.binned_statistic` but I am failing to apply any of the two to get my desired binning. Maybe the latter should be the easiest to use for this case as it offers the parameter `statistic=<function>` but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Did you take a look at numpy.histogram? It supports binning with weights.

Comment: Yes but I don't quite get how this would look like... I need a specific example to start off but unfortunately I cannot find (m)any